# Typescript asserting an import is being exported with Jest

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I am writing a small library in typescript doing TDD. I am finding its complex to do an assertion that my main file is exporting some of my interfaces. 
The next test fails to compile with an error of `'X' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here`.

```js
jest.mock('../lib/supervisor', () => jest.fn())
import ISupervisor from '../lib/supervisor'

import { ISupervisor as exportedISupervisor } from '../lib/index'

describe('index', () => {
  it('should export supervisor', () => {
    expect(exportedISupervisor).toBe(ISupervisor)
  })
})
```

The intention is to assert that main has something like:

```js
import ISupervisor from './supervisor'
export { ISupervisor }
```

What is wrong on my test? How could I mock the import to assert the export?

Answer (score 1):

You've already indirectly asserted that the main exports `ISupervisor` interface when you did:

```
import { ISupervisor as exportedISupervisor } from '../lib/index'
```

If the Interface wasn't in the file, the typescript compiler will fail on that line.

Jest isn't the right tool for this. Jest itself isn't aware of any of typescripts types and interfaces.

Comment: that is actually not true, you assert exists but you dont assert is correct export. Jest is the correct tool because you can mock imports and assert equality. I do it every day in JS but the TS compiler complains in this case.

Comment: Unlike classes, an `interface` is a virtual structure that only exists within the context of TypeScript. So you would not be able to mock an interface with jest since jest runs on the already compiled code.